# JavaScript Bootstrap is not working

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am very new to Bootstrap and trying to convert my HTML and JavaScript to Bootstrap. This is the code for my HTML which has the script as well. I think I am missing a footer but I am not sure. It is supposed to be an order form. It works completely fine without the Bootstrap on it. I don't think I am using jQuery for this but if I should then I will use that as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Order Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="bootstrap-4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: #2C3E50;  
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50);  
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50);
            font-family: helvetica;
            text-align: center
        }

        table {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            text-align: center; 
            background-color: #7de5f3;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: rgb(61, 234, 247);
            border-width: medium;
            padding: 8px
        }
    </style>
    <style>
        input[id^=Qty] { width:5em; }
        td:first-child { width:80px; }
    </style>
</head> 
<body>
    <h1 style="color : white"> Gift Shop </h1> 
    <form>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Bootstrap.css" media="screen" />
        <div class="divTable">
            <div class="divTableBody">
                <div class="divTableRow">
                    <div class="divTableHead">Item</div>
                    <div class="divTableHead">Image</div>
                    <div class="divTableHead">Quantity</div>
                    <div class="divTableHead">Price</div>
                    <div class="divTableHead">Total</div>
                </div>
                <div class="divTableRow">
                    <div class="divTableCell">Hat</div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><img src="images/hat.gif" alt="Hat" /></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><input id="QtyA" type="text" /></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell">$3.00</div>
                    <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="divTableRow">
                    <div class="divTableCell">T Shirt</div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><img src="images/t_shirt.gif" alt="T-Shirt" /></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><input id="QtyB" type="text" /></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell">$4.00</div>
                    <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="divTableRow">
                    <div class="divTableCell">Glasses</div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><img src="images/glasses.gif" alt="Glasses" /></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><input id="QtyC" type="text" /></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell">$5.00</div>
                    <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="divTableRow">
                    <div class="divTableCell">Total:</div>
                    <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Get Grand Total">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
<script>    
    var qtyBoxA = document.getElementById('QtyA');
    var qtyBoxB = document.getElementById('QtyB');
    var qtyBoxC = document.getElementById('QtyC');

    var totBoxA = document.getElementById('TotalA');
    var totBoxB = document.getElementById('TotalB');
    var totBoxC = document.getElementById('TotalC');

    var grandTot = document.getElementById('grandTotal');
    var btnGetTot = document.querySelector("input[type=button]");
    var btnReset = document.querySelector("input[type=reset]");    

    qtyBoxA.addEventListener("change", calc);
    qtyBoxB.addEventListener("change", calc);
    qtyBoxC.addEventListener("change", calc);
    btnGetTot.addEventListener("click", getGrandTotal);
    btnReset.addEventListener("click", reset);

    var gt = null; 

    function calc() {
        var priceA = 3;
        var priceB = 4;
        var priceC = 5;
        gt = 0; 

        var qtyA = parseInt(qtyBoxA.value, 10);
        var qtyB = parseInt(qtyBoxB.value, 10);
        var qtyC = parseInt(qtyBoxC.value, 10);

        if (!isNaN(qtyA)) { totBoxA.textContent = qtyA * priceA; gt += +totBoxA.textContent; }
        if (!isNaN(qtyB)) { totBoxB.textContent = qtyB * priceB; gt += +totBoxB.textContent; }
        if (!isNaN(qtyC)) { totBoxC.textContent = qtyC * priceC; gt += +totBoxC.textContent; }

        grandTot.textContent = gt.toFixed(2); 
    }

    function getGrandTotal(){
        calc(); 
        alert(gt);    
    }

    function reset(){          
        totBoxA.textContent = "";
        totBoxB.textContent = "";
        totBoxC.textContent = "";      
        grandTot.textContent = "";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is it that you want to do here?

Answer (score 1):

For bootstrap 4 to work properly you need jquery and popper.js 
so load these before bootstrap js